# Maximum number of relationships for given amount of objects

Tags: combinatorics

Say I've got 4 objects: a,b,c,d

These objects can be linked together in a 1 to 1 relationship: e.g: a to b (b to a would be the same relationship, so we ignore that)

So we have 6 possible relationships in total:

```
a to b
a to c
a to d
b to c
b to d
c to d
```

What would be the formula to work how many relationships a given number of objects has? For instance, instead of 4 objects say we had 45, how what would be the maximum number of relationships for that amount of objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to find the number of 2-combinations of the set. For a set of $n$ elements, the number of 2-combinations is

$$
\binom{n}{2} = \frac{n!}{2\times (n-2)!}
$$

Answer (score 2):

In general; the number of ways to choose $r$ objects from $n$ distinct objects is given by the formula: $$\binom{n}{r} = \frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$$ In your specific case $n=4$ and $r=2$ so $$\binom{4}{2}=\frac{4!}{2!(4-2)!}=6$$ and for $n=45$ and $r=2$ then $$\binom{45}{2}=\frac{45!}{2!(45-2)!}=990$$